# Too Many Columns Error With Nested List in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a data structure of nested lists. Each cell in the pandas DataFrame should have a nested list.

I have tried the following;

First I have a list of headings:

```
headings = ["heading1", "heading2", "heading3", "heading4", "heading5", "heading6"]
```

I then have my data structure:

```
data_list = [[foo, bar], [foo1, bar1], [foo2, bar2], [foo3, bar3], [foo4, bar4], [foo5, bar5], [bar, foo], [bar1, foo1], [bar2, foo2], [bar3, foo3], [bar4, foo4], [bar5, foo5]]
```

What I want to achieve is to create a pandas dataframe and for every 6th item in the data structure we start a new row in the pandas dataframe. In the example above this means there would be two rows with 6 columns.

What I have tried so far is the following;

Generated a row index from the length of the data structure:

```
idx =[i for i in range((len(data_list) / 6))]
```

I have then tried to generate the Dataframe using the columns vs the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=headings, index=idx)
```

In this case I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 12 columns
```

My question is, how can I start a new row every 6th item in the nested list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data_list is in list format convert that into numpy array

```
import numpy as np
data_list = np.array(data_list)
```

Now use reshape method to change the data into 2 rows and 6 columns

```
data_list  = data_list.reshape([2,6,2])
```

output:

```
array([[['foo', 'bar'],
        ['foo1', 'bar1'],
        ['foo2', 'bar2'],
        ['foo3', 'bar3'],
        ['foo4', 'bar4'],
        ['foo5', 'bar5']],

       [['bar', 'foo'],
        ['bar1', 'foo1'],
        ['bar2', 'foo2'],
        ['bar3', 'foo3'],
        ['bar4', 'foo4'],
        ['bar5', 'foo5']]], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful!